# Best place for learning how to write games in Unity3d

Tags: unity

What's the best place for tutorials & other learning resources for unity3d?

Comment: For me these can be the most valuable threads. When I want a book or tutorial I always start at SO

Comment: http://www.walkerboystudio.com/html/unity_training___free__.html

Comment: self-plug: checkout my book Unity in Action! http://www.manning.com/UnityinAction

Answer (score 16):

- [Unity Documentation](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/)
- [Learn Unity 3D](http://learnunity3d.com/)
- [Jason 3D Buzz unity videos](http://forum.unity3d.com/viewtopic.php?t=39327)
- [Introduction to Game Development Using Unity 3D](http://www.vtc.com/products/introduction-to-game-development-using-unity-3d-tutorials.htm) (Commercial video tutorial)

Comment: The 3D buzz tutorials were great, recommended to anyone who already knows c# as that's the language they use for scripting.

Comment: Especially since Unity hasn't completed it's C# Documentation.

Comment: Looks like the 3d Buss tutorials are not available anymore. Have a look here http://www.3dbuzz.com/training

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the documentation and the unity forums, I recommend the Unity question & answer site:

http://answers.unity3d.com/

Comment: I was not aware there was a Unity StackExchange site, thanks.

Comment: @jhocking Yeah it was created back in the day, before the Area 51 approval process existed. Although looking at it now, it looks like they've switched over to a different Q&A Engine

Comment: ohh I think I'd seen the old version

Comment: I found UnityAnswers users, especially the newcomers do not completely understand the system and they post replies as answers (instead of comments) and they stuff anything in the tag box ("set script variable different gameobject", notice the word order and the "set")
, well, one of the most important things to learn is the singleton

Comment: Looks like the stack unitys' stack exchange has a new design and makes more fun to work with!

Answer (score 8):

There's a giant community wiki of tutorials and resources on Unity's answer's site:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/12321/how-can-i-start-learning-unity-fast-list-of-tutori.html

Answer (score 6):

I've just started following these in my own learning, and found them to be top notch, tons of videos already added:

http://unity3dstudent.com

Answer (score 6):

I've been following a free video tutorial series by the "Tornado Twins" on YouTube. It's turned out to be a really excellent series that covers quite a lot over the course of writing a simple 3d adventure game. I would **highly** recommend this to others.

http://www.youtube.com/user/TornadoTwins

Also at Keyframe's recommendation I've also started following the 2.5D video series at 3dBuzz but while I'm finding it informative I'm not a fan of their presentation style as there's a lot of fluff and something that could be presented in 10 minutes takes 20 minutes with all the idle chit chat. But still very helpful.

Comment: I found these videos extremely helpful as well. I generally don't like video tutorials, and YouTube seems like an odd place to find excellent learning materials, but there ya go.

Answer (score 5):

Unity has it's own excellent documentation: http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/

Answer (score 5):

When I was learning Unity, the most helpful thing was going through the Lerpz tutorial (http://unity3d.com/support/resources/tutorials/3d-platform-game), but then (and probably even more helpful) going through the FPS Shooter tutorial ([http://unity3d.com/support/resources/tutorials/fpstutorial](http://unity3d.com/support/resources/tutorials/3d-platform-game)).

Going through those two tutorials helped immensely, more than any other tutorials, and even the Unity Development book.

Answer (score 2):

I have a brand new Unity 4 course I put together for beginners on Udemy called Anyone Can Learn to Make a Game. https://www.udemy.com/unity-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

The unity forums also contain a wealth of information. You'll be hard pressed, starting out, to come up with questions that others before you didn't have as well, and it's a pretty helpful bunch overthere.