# Start work Unity 3d

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best place for learning how to write games in Unity3d](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/222/best-place-for-learning-how-to-write-games-in-unity3d)

Hi all,

I am just a new candidate who is going to work upon the `Unity 3D` game engine so guys I need some help to get some good tutorials where I can learn the moving characters, effects, and creating the surroundings.

Is there a place where I can get some links or pdf with which I can learn `Unity` in little time?

Thanks!

Comment: This is an effective duplicate of http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/222/best-place-for-learning-how-to-write-games-in-unity3d
Can we close and mark as duplicate?

Comment: You should also not stay too long on the tutorials and get your hands dirty. Find an idea and create it, and stay focused on easy things at the beginning!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already know basic programming, go there:
http://unity3dstudent.com/

Comment: hey xeon i have worked with the iphone/ipad programming but never worked on the any game engine .So need help from person like you .

Thanks..

Comment: You need help from a person like yourself, to show initiative and learn what you need to learn.

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/ is a specific forum for Unity3D developers.