# What knowledge do I need to learn Unity?

Tags: unity

What do I need to get into using Unity? Do I need some knowledge in any language in particular?  Can I just get to know the program with tutorials? What would you recommend?

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/222/best-place-for-learning-how-to-write-games-in-unity3d

Comment: This question is really unanswerable.  What does "using Unity" mean?  There's lots of stuff you *can* do in Unity, all of which requires some kind of knowledge.

Comment: You'll need this sooner or later: https://www.khanacademy.org/cs/tutorials/programming-basics

Answer (score 2):

The only knowledge you need is how to operate your web browser, read English and a link to the [Unity Manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/index.html). (Judging by your question here, I think you have the first two).

From there, you can learn everything you need to know about what you don't know yet. Pick it up and learn as you go with tutorials and further searches on the internet for the things you're not sure about.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn quite a bit from online tutorials and by visiting the Unity site and having a peak at the documentation. You can code in Unity using UnityScript(JavaScript), Boo and C#. Many beginning developers will opt to code in UnityScript and as they get more comfortable many switch over to C#.

I created a course for beginners using Unity 4 you may be interested in on Udemy. You can find more info about it here https://www.udemy.com/unity-tutorial/.

Welcome to the Unity :-)